# how to use a previous stored item after a fold gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

First, I'm using azure cosmos graph db.

I see this sort of pattern quite a bit:

```
out('an-edge').fold().coalesce(unfold(),addV('incoming-schedule'))
```

I want to add an edge immediately after I do an addV in the coalesce.  I've been trying to do it in a simple example:

```
g.V('any-vertex-id').as('a').out('an-edge').coalesce(unfold(),addV('new-vertex').addE('to-v').from('a'))
```

"a" seems to no longer exist after a fold() since it's a barrier step.  I tried store and aggregate but I must not understand those properly.  Is it possible to get a reference after a fold()?  I need it because it may reference a previous addV in the query to which I wouldn't have the id yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your requirement here? Do you want to create a new vertex an edge only when out('an-edge') is not present?

If that's the case, I will try this:

```
g.V('any-vertex-id').as('a').coalesce(out('an-edge'), addV('new-vertex').addE('to-v').from(select('a')))
```

Fold() is typically used when one needs to aggregate on all the output from the preceding step. I don't think, that is necessary in this case.

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#fold-step

Comment: after having used this a few times, I do think this makes more sense then what I was doing and does answer the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can store and then select from it when adding the edge.

```
g.V('any-vertex-id').store('a').out('an-edge').fold()
           .coalesce(unfold(),addV('new-vertex')
                    .addE('to-v').from(select('a').unfold()))
```

Not sure if someone has a better alternative or a better suggestion then store, but this seems to work at least in my scenario